# correlation coefficient between columns of 2 dataframes

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes as given below.

```
>>> df1
   c1  c2
0  10  10
1  20  11
2  40  15
3   9  20
4  13  27
>>> df2
    k1   k2
0  100  100
1  200  115
2  400  159
3   80  202
4   90  270
```

I would to compute correlation between Ks and Cs, something like given below

```
>>df3
          c1      c2
   k1     .99     -0.31
   k2     -0.16     .98
```

Assuming data represented in df3 is correct , .99 is correlation coefficient between c1 & k1 , .35 is between c2 & k1 so on .. 
How this can be computed?

Comment: How did you compute those output values, e.g. how is `.35 is between c2 & k1?

Comment: I did not compute . This is with assumption that these values are correct. Idea is apply logic for this computation and get result in desired format

Comment: `This is with assumption that these values are correct` - What's the reference on that correctness?

Comment: edited values in df3

Comment: How are you arriving at that value? What's the formula? Any references?

Comment: corrxy = pearsonr(x,y)[0] where x and y is list of values of columns in question

Comment: `corr2_coeff(df2.values.T, df1.values.T)` from the linked dup Q's accepted soln.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this,

```
a=df1.columns.values
b=df2.columns.values
print   [df1[u].corr(df2[v]) for u,v in  list(itertools.product(a, b))]
```